# A stricter limit where $0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow \color{red}{0<} |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta, substitution

The familiar definition of a limit is that we say $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L$ when

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0 : 0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon.$$

I've been doing a little bit of work with limits lately and have come across a situation where it has been useful to define a new sort of limit, say ${\lim}^\dagger$, that is defined so that we can say $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \rightarrow a}}^\dagger f(x) = L$ when

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0 : 0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow \color{red}{0<} |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon.$$

(The modified portion is indicated in red.)

**Question:** Does this type of stricter limit ${\lim}^\dagger$ have any sort of standard name, notation, or known properties?

---

*Background:*

I was doing a bit of toying around with situations when

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x) = G \text{ and } \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow G} f(x) = L \text{ imply that } \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(g(x)) = L. \tag{1}$$

I was able to determine that this seems to hold when $\displaystyle {\lim_{x\rightarrow a}}^\dagger g(x) = G$, with ${\lim}^\dagger$ being as defined above. I don't think this is the only circumstance when (1) holds, but it was at least a straightforward enough starting place in my investigation. So, this is what led me to be asking about ${\lim}^\dagger$.

Comment: Where did you find such a notion of limit? by yourself? Do you have any application in  mind for which you may want to restric $f$ to not take the value $L$? it seems to contrive a definition.

Comment: Such a definition is really odd... I.e a constant map has no limit at any point.

Comment: OliverDíaz and mathcounterexamples.net, please see the "background" section at the bottom. :)

Comment: @TrevorKafka: that does not say how that notion of limit came about. Like I said, it seems to contrived.

Comment: It is contrived—it's a definition I wrote to satisfy the condition I specified.

Comment: A function that is continuous${}^\dagger$ (i.e., using $\lim^\dagger$ in the definition) must additionally be strictly monotonic …

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Hmm, I'm pretty sure $y = x^2$ is continuous${}^\dagger$, but not monotonic.